# Backup SQL Server database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup

I'm trying to backup a SQL Server database using this code:

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
string database = con.Database.ToString();

try
{
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "SQL Server database backup files|*.bak";
    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Database Backup";
    saveFileDialog1.FileName = "GestionStock.bak";

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string sqlStmt = string.Format("USE MASTER BACKUP DATABASE [" + database +"] TO DISK='{0}'", saveFileDialog1.FileName);

        using (SqlCommand bu2 = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt, con))
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            bu2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Base de données sauvegardée avec success");
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

This code works and creates a backup file but when I try to re-backup the database I got this error message:

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Try it without the `USE MASTER`.

Comment: I tried it but the same error occured

Comment: are you sure that the string `database` actually has a value that is different then `string.Empty`?

Comment: Yes i'm sure that it has a value

Comment: @user4340666, check the backup command being executed.  I'll bet it is not what you expect (i.e. empty database name).  Also, be aware that the backup file path is from the SQL Server machine rather than the client so this app can't run remotely unless the dialog constructs a UNC path that both the SQL Server and client can access.